# Qt Icon not shown on Linux

Tags: qt, ubuntu, icons

I am trying to make my app (FlatSiteBuilder) show an icon on the taskbar on Ubuntu.
A small demo app is doing that correctly using the following code.

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.setWindowIcon(QIcon(QLatin1String(":/images/icon.svg")));
```

But when I try to do this in my app only the QuestionMarkIcon is shown.
When I try to change the TARGET of my demo app to FlatSiteBuilder in the .pro file the icon is not shown anymore.
When I try to change the TARGET of my demo app to Gimp for example then the Gimp-Icon is shown.

Where is the information stored that Ubuntu is showing the Gimp-Icon?
Where is the information stored that Ubuntu is not showing an Icon for FlatSiteBuilder?

My .pro file
`TARGET = IconTest` -> shows the correct icon
`TARGET = IconTest2` -> shows the correct icon
`TARGET = FlatSiteBuilder` -> shows the questionmark icon
`TARGET = Gimp` -> shows the Gimp icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Windows or macOS (where the application icons are bundled with executables), Linux acts a bit different when in comes to such resources. In fact, there are multiple locations where the icons can be stored. For example, you can place your SVG icon file here:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/FlatSiteBuilder.svg
```

And then refresh the GTK icon cache from your terminal:

```
sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*
```

Comment: Oh, a cache...then the behaviour makes sense...
Its working now without any changes. Just switched to debug mode. Recopile the app and the icon was visible. Now also the AppImage shows the icon.